# What is the best way to implement a Singleton which satisfies the following requirements in Java?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, thread-safety, singleton

In our android app, we have the following requirements

1. Pre-load all the Typefaces that we use
2. Cache the loaded Typefaces

Till now, we had a simple singleton which looked like this :

```
@NotThreadSafe
public static void init(Context context) { 

 if (instance == null) {
            instance = new TypefaceHelper(context);
            instance.setAssetManager(context.getAssets());
            instance.setAllTypefaces();
  }
}
```

The following are the problems I ran into :

- Its not thread-safe .Note that , till now its always accessed in Main-Thread ( but from different classes)
- setAllTypefaces() takes more than 50 ms on
  average to load the 4 typefaces we are using .

So, everytime when MyApplication ( which extends Android's Application gets called ), our typeface initialization itself was taking more than 50 ms .

As part of performance tuning, we decided it makes sense to load the typefaces in the background . So, now I want to load the typefaces in background and also to make the init thread safe.

This is the design I came up with

```
public class TypefaceHelper {

   private static TypefaceHelper instance;

   private volatile Typeface proximaRegular;

   private final Object typefaceLock = new Object();

   private static final Object constructorLock = new Object();



@GuardedBy("constructorLock")
public static void init(Context context) {

    synchronized (constructorLock) {

        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new TypefaceHelper(context);
            instance.setAssetManager(context.getAssets());
            MyApplicationHelper.getInstance().getExecutorService().execute(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    instance.setAllTypefaces();  // Set up all Typefaces in background thread
                }
            });

        }
    }

}


@Nullable 
public static TypefaceHelper getInstance() { // Existing code used in 100+ places. Not touched now.
    return instance;
}

// Accessing a typeface. Use Double-checked locking to ensure it works 
public Typeface getProximaRegular() {
    if(proximaRegular==null){ // The variable must be volatile to prevent compiler re-orderings and optimizations
        synchronized (typefaceLock){
            if(proximaRegular==null){
                proximaRegular = Typeface.createFromAsset(assetManager, "fonts/ProximaNova-Regular.otf");
            }
        }
    }
    return proximaRegular;
}


@GuardedBy("typefaceLock")
private void setAllTypefaces(){


    synchronized (typefaceLock) {


        proximaRegular = Typeface.createFromAsset(assetManager, "fonts/ProximaNova-Regular.otf");

        // Initialize 3 other typefaces here 


    }


  }

}
```

Note that I am using a null-check outside the synchronized block in getProxmimaRegular() because its being accessed from 100+ places and I dont want a lock to be acquired if its not null .

My questions are :

1) Is this a bad practice to load member variables of a singleton in background ? ( Otherwise performance gets impacted big time )

2) is using a separate lock for init() an overkill here ?

3) How can I make this better considering my requirements ?

Comment: 1. It's case dependent. I'd guess you could use a form of lazy loading of your `TypeFace` . 2. Not necessarily though you might want to check the `Lock` class provided by the standard API (if nothing else for clarity). 3. You should profile your program to see where the most time is spent and prioritize what can be improved

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I figured out a better way to implement this by using ReentrantLocks